# Does installing Perl DBD-mysql-4.021 need MySQL header on MacOs Lion?

Tags: mysql, macos, perl, dbd

I try to install DBD-mysql-4.021 on MacOS Lion, but it seems when I do, it misses some header file.

```
MacBook-Pro-de-benoit:DBD-mysql-4.021-XXi0wV vanalder$ sudo make 
llvm-gcc-4.2 -c -I/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/DBI -I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -g -DDBD_MYSQL_INSERT_ID_IS_GOOD -g  -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -Os   -DVERSION=\"4.021\" -DXS_VERSION=\"4.021\"  "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   dbdimp.c In file included from dbdimp.c:20: 
dbdimp.h:24:49: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory 
dbdimp.h:25:45: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory 
dbdimp.h:27:49: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory In file included from dbdimp.c:20: dbdimp.h:159: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL’ dbdimp.h:257: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL_RES’ In file included from dbdimp.c:20:
....
```

I tried installing binaries of MySQL from [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/). I can install but it doesn't work. Or install it with macports (mysql5-devel -> cannot install), what should I do to use MySQL with Perl?

---

I installed again mysql from a DMG from this link [http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/][1]http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ 
but i still have the same error when i make

```
sudo make

dbdimp.h:24:49: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
dbdimp.h:25:45: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory
dbdimp.h:27:49: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory
In file included from dbdimp.c:20:
dbdimp.h:159: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL’
dbdimp.h:257: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL_RES’
In file included from dbdimp.c:20:
....
```

It's the first time i  have trouble to install a CPAN module (Xcode install and a GCC compiler k)

Comment: you can get MYSQL from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must have MySQL installed to get the client to work as it depends on the MySQL client code. I usually use the DMG download available from MySQL, which includes an installer for MySQL, an installer for the startup script, and a preferences pane:

- http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Make sure you get the correct platform for your system. **Edit:** As Quentin pointed out, the question is about Lion, which is always 64-bit.

Comment: It's Lion, that only runs on the 64-bit Intels AFAIK. Certainly doesn't run on the G5.

Comment: The problem is that i already have mysql on Lion ( one installed with pkg and one come with mamp).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself, i was using the MAMP installation directory of mysql but obviously it's not complete, so after reinstalled mysql i simply used this option for :

```
sudo perle Makefile.pl --mysqlconfig=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqlconfig
```